# Short form for "Indicaciones sobre la protección de datos"

Tags: sinónimos

As the title says, I need a short form for the phrase:

"Indicaciones sobre la protección de datos"

It shouldn't be longer than 3-4 words. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: What would you use in English?

Comment: It is for a website. The short form should appear in a navigation. Since the space is pretty small I wanted to have such a short form! I am satisfied with all your suggestions! For English I use Privacy Policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more context, it's going to be hard, but you could try

> - Indicaciones sobre la privacidad
> - Política de privacidad

Comment: Facebook has a page, "política de privacidad"

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Alexis that more context would help ... but if it's for something like a sub-heading in a document, you could just drop the "Indicaciones sobre la" and go with:

> Protección de datos

I also like Alexis' "Política de privacidad", but "privacy" is a more general concept than "data protection", so it might not be applicable to your case.

Answer (score 0):

"Protección de datos" would be the closest way to summarize what you are trying to expose. It's brief and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Cómo proteger sus datos.

I do subtitling for a living, and finding ways of saying it all with the least amount of characters is a must in this trade.